# java about IntelliJ Button

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have see other's IntelliJ like this:

[image]

and mine looks like this:

[image]

what can I do to get the slider button?

Comment: lower left corner there is a button to show/hide the side bars - it looks like a square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should click here: (the button which in red line)
[image]